# Jquery featured content slider

Tags: jquery

Does anybody know what the best way to achieve a Jquery content slider/accordion similar to the [BBC iPlayer Featured/Most Popular](http://www.bbc.co.uk/iplayer/) one? It's a bit more complex than what is available/searchable on Google.

Any help greatly apprecaited / thanks for any ideas, S.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Slidedeck would be a very good base for this - http://www.slidedeck.com/

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I ended up using/hacking http://tympanus.net/codrops/2010/04/26/elegant-accordion-with-jquery-and-css3/ though as the slidedeck didn't work on IE6 : (